# Where is the Daylight saving time setting in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, date-time

I can't find how to disable the Daylight saving time option in windows7 !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on the clock on the bottom right of the screen

Change date and time settings...

change time zone

There is a check box saying : automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time

[image]

Comment: in Windows 7 there not such checkbox ! do you have windows 7 ?

Comment: Yes I'm on windows 7 , but if you are using a time with no daylight saving, the checkbox will not be there.

Comment: :) i didn't see it

Comment: On most systems, If the zone/location you have selected doesn't do DaylightSavings then the check box is not there.

Comment: maybe that's why, I have changed the location many times

Comment: Novembre? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novembre

Comment: Yeah Novembre, like November, but in French.

Comment: @user8228 , it's really there. Just change to US&Canada time zone first, it will show.