# Timezone in Windows and Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, time

On the same machine I am using Win 7 and Debian Linux (KDE). I have issues with the timezone settings. Both systems are set to London time, but the clock in Windows (before it gets adjusted over the Internet) shows one hour behind. How can I configure this in such a way that both systems agree on the system time?

Answer (score 5):

Probably Linux is configured to use hardware clock as UTC, whereas Windows wants the hardware clock to be set to the "wall time". Since you're dual booting, you'll need to configure Linux to not use UTC for the hardware clock.

Some linux distributions use

```
/etc/sysconfig/clock
```

whereas Ubuntu and Debian use

```
/etc/default/rcS
```

In this file change UTC=true to UTC=false

You can use the command

```
hwclock --systohc --localtime
```

to set the hardware clock from within Linux.

Comment: I can't find file `/etc/rcS` on my Debian system. There is `/etc/rcS.d`, but it is a directory with soft links to start-up scripts...

Comment: It's /etc/default/rcS on my Ubuntu systems. I've updated the original answer to reflect that.

Comment: I actually found in the man page for rcS the following `The  UTC  setting  is  replaced  by  the  UTC  or  LOCAL setting in /etc/adjtime, and should have been migrated automatically.  See hwclock(5) and
       hwclock(8) for further details on configuring the system clock.` I will report further after investigation.

Comment: I don't see this in the man page for rcS on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (the current and latest version).

Comment: Maybe Debian is different...

Answer (score 3):

Is daylight savings turned on in Windows?

For dual boot systems, you could take the time from the BIOS clock. This would solve your issue.

Comment: I think so. Where can I double check?

Comment: See this link: http://superuser.com/questions/35544/where-is-the-daylight-saving-time-setting-in-windows-7

Comment: Yes, I confirm that the daylight saving is turned on in Windows.

Comment: and is it also for the Linux OS?

Comment: Actually, there is no specific option in KDE (after logging into Linux). However, the time did change correctly on the day when DST started.

Comment: Post has been updated

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: not yet. I tries Colin's answer recently (was away earlier) but I couldn't find one of the files (see my comment to his answer).